# How to get and send Data from/to an SVG document and use in PHP?

Tags: php, svg

Anyone can give a Simple Example of Code that how to use SVG Data in PHP and also How to Send SVG data using PHP to the SVG Document to manipulate them (lets Suppose a Form having Values of an SVG Element and sending those values to Svg Doc)...!!

Answer (score 0):

SVG files are regular XML documents. See http://www.devx.com/webdev/Article/37004 and http://www.phpbuilder.com/columns/ken_coar20081201.php3